# Fix bash_profile to Develop Ruby on Rails Apps

Tags: terminal, ruby, ruby-on-rails, .bash-profile

I just installed Ruby and Rails stuff on my machine, and start to learn.

But every time I close the Terminal and re-open it, I have to re-type the command **. ~/.bash_profile** in order to run Rails commands properly...

How can i fix this, to close and re-open the Terminal, ready to develop my Rails apps?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: .bash_profile is read when you login and .bashrc is read when you start a new terminal. Have you tried to restart the system? Is bash your default terminal?

Comment: i'm running mint linux, debian-like system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open .bash_profile and you should see these 2 lines:

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #
>   Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Copy these lines and append them to your .bashrc file and you're done!